# Ship not moving, python crash course chapter 12

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The ship won't move, but it doesn't return errors.
This is really frustrating.

*alien_invasion.py*

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

*game_functions.py*

```
import sys
import pygame

def check_events(ship):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = False
        elif event == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = False

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour)
        ship.blitme()
```

*settings.py*

```py
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        #screen stuff
        self.screen_width = 1000
        self.screen_height = 750
        self.bg_colour = (0, 0, 0)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
```

*ship.py*

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Also, here is [ship.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DttQJ.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`event` is an object, the type of the event is stored in the attribute `.type`. Thus you have to evaluate `if event.type == ...:` rather than `if event == ...:`:
(See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html))

```py
def check_events(ship):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = False
```